# Buscar valores dentro de una lista dentro de un diccionario

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter

Tengo un diccionario con listas:

```
personal_proyecto = {'jefe_proyecto':{
                        'Nombre':'Juan',
                        'Edad': 28,
                        'Experiencia':['Gestion','Finanzas','Bases de datos'],
                        'Residencia':'Madrid',
                        'HorasProyecto':3500},
                    'empleados':[{
                        'Nombre':'Elena',
                        'Edad': 26,
                        'Experiencia':['JavaScript','Python'],
                        'Residencia':'Madrid',
                        'HorasProyecto':500},{
                        'Nombre':'Luis',
                        'Edad': 31,
                        'Experiencia':['Django','Flask','Pyramid'],
                        'Residencia':'Barcelona',
                        'HorasProyecto':1100                    
                        }]
                    }
```

Necesito crear un bucle que recorra el numero de empleados del diccionario y para cada empleado (en este caso 2) haga un append a una variable lista llamada horas_empleado.

```
horas_jefe = personal_proyecto ['jefe_proyecto']['HorasProyecto']
print (horas_jefe)
horas_empleados = []
for horas, empleados in personal_proyecto.items(): 
    if empleados == 'HorasProyecto':
        horas_empledados.append [horas]
print (horas_empleados)
```

Comment: `horas_empleados = [ empl['HorasProyecto'] for empl in personal_proyecto['empleados'] ]`

Comment: No creo que la estructura de tu diccionario esté bien establecida

Answer (score 0):

```
horas_empleados = [i['HorasProyecto'] for i in personal_proyecto['empleados']]
print(horas_empleados)
```

Esto te imprimirá las horas de cada empleado en una lista, si quieres podemos seguirlo modificando para que quede aun mas legible. Pero el resultado da!

> [500, 1100]